# Pyinstaller giving error ("Error loading Python ... no suitable image found")

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I have this is issue with pyinstaller on Mac that gives this error when I click on the created executable:

```
[9888] Error loading Python lib '/Users/Faris/Downloads/as5/dist/startscreen/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/Faris/Downloads/as5/dist/startscreen/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/Faris/Downloads/as5/dist/startscreen/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/Faris/Downloads/as5/dist/startscreen/Python'
```

This is a GUI application that uses PIL and 4 PNG files. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Take note that on macOS, python3.7.7 or + and python3.8.3 or + are giving the same error, because of the addition of a full-notarization signing for python to avoid gatekeeper alerts.

Just install Python 3.7.6 or Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I had resolved the same trouble with the following:

1. `pip3 uninstall pyinstaller`
2. `brew reinstall python`
3. `brew install pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1):

I found how to make it work. After the Python lib is in your dist folder, run:

```
codesign -f -s - Python
```

Then run the application.

I have a theory what the problem is but I'm not sure. I think the Python lib is signed, but when PyInstaller moves it from its original place, the signature verification fails.

What the command does is to replace the signature with an [ad-hoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccodesignatureflags/1397793-adhoc) signature, which allows you to run the application locally, but probably doesn't count as a signature for distribution. I can't say I fully understand it.

Before you ship the application you probably want to replace the ad-hoc signature with a proper signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install lastest dev version from PyInstaller:

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```